# MySQL WHERE x OR IS NULL not working

Tags: mysql, centos, where-clause, mariadb, isnull

```
select * from inventory.home_picture_types hpt
left join inventory.home_pictures hp on hp.home_picture_type_id = hpt.id
where hp.id IS NULL;
```

This query works on vagrant/homestead, and returns the home_picture_types with NULL home_picture values (correct, I'm just trying to get the home_picture_types).

However, when I run this query on CentOS Maria DB, it returns no results at all. It's *as though* the LEFT JOIN is an INNER JOIN.

I have written this query 700 different ways, and nothing is helping. I checked the sql_mode and it's set to '' on both databases.... Any ideas why it works on one and not the other??

Comment: NULL is never equal to anything including itself. Your SQL doesn't make sense.

Comment: `select * from inventory.home_picture_types hpt
left join inventory.home_pictures hp on hp.home_picture_type_id = hpt.id
where hp.id='';` try this.

Comment: It should return the rows that don't have a matching hpt.id and hp.home_picture_type, right? I'm trying to get where they don't match, which would just return something like: http://tinypic.com/r/243pzti/9

Comment: Your suggestion returns nothing just as = NULL does, but I didn't try that at first..

Comment: You sure the database has the same data?  I don't see anything wrong with your query...

Comment: Ya as far as I can tell. I truncated the tables, and copied/pasted the data into the table again. (just the 5 rows in the image). Do you think that the table could be corrupted or something? I just created it like 30 mins ago.

Comment: Well I have a link where 9 man hours were burned on this site, and in the end, it was the wrong database. So, recheck stuff cuz you are talking about different boxes and inter-db joins

Comment: Ah damnit. The data was not the same. The home_pictures table was empty in homestead. SOOO, would have any suggestions on a query to retrieve the results I'd like? I just need all the home_picture_types no matter what, and if there no home_picture that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

All the types:  `select DISTINCT home_picture_type_id from inventory.home_picture_types`.

Types for which there is no pic:  `select home_picture_type_id from inventory.home_picture_types AS hpt WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM inventory.home_pictures WHERE home_picture_type_id = hpt.id )`.